# Архитектура web приложения golang + Firebase

Tags: golang, firebase, ember.js

Добрый день, уважаемые.
Помогите старому сишнику разобраться в современной web разработке.
Создаю сайт на golang, базу хочу держать в Firebase. Возникает вопрос наиболее умной архитектуры. Стоит ли напрямую делать эту связку или лучше использовать какой-нибудь фреймворк типа ember js?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Благодарю. Постараюсь более внятно выразить запрос.
Разрабатываю web сайт, back-end пишу на golang, данные храню в Firebase. Каких-то нестандартных и специфичных требований к проекту у меня нет.
Я плохо разбираюсь во всем множестве фреймворков и решений в сфере web, которые существуют на данный момент. Потому прошу помочь мне разобраться в инструментах, которыми будет уместно пользоваться.
В данный момент вся все довольно просто:
golang + firebase + javascript + bootstrap.
С Firebase взаимодействие идет только со стороны js, golang к базе не обращается.

Comment: Отсюда вытекают основные вопросы.
Данная концепция, когда c Firebase работает только javascript, нормальна ли?
Есть ли у кого-нибудь советы по замене или добавке какого-либо инструмента?